# Facebook opengraph image tag reading but no image appearing

Tags: image, facebook-opengraph

For example see:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.disabilitydirectory.net.au%2Fmaking-it-work-a-workforce-guide-for-disability-service-providers%2F

I can not get the images on my posts to display, despite increasing their size. I ran the debug, and it is finding the og tag, but it says the image is less than 200 x 200 (it's not!) and that it will use another image instead.  The image it refers to is even smaller.  But it doesn't use that either.

Comment: Problem solved.  Issue with hotlinks and access to images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a parameter after the img:

http://www.disabilitydirectory.net.au/wp-content/uploads/making-it-work5.png**?t=12345?**

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem. Follow another thread with a similar question and tried all the solutions but none worked. I changed 2 things and it worked for me. Not sure which change made it work though.

1. I changed the name of the file so Facebook has to search for a new file instead of working with a potential cached version.
2. I added "www." in front of all my links and made sure all the root links matched perfectly.

Here's my working meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website"> 
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/fb.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:url" 
      content="https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/fb.jpg"
>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" 
      content="https://www.MYWEBSITE.com/fb.jpg"
>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.MYWEBSITE.com">
```

Here are other solutions I tried as well, that worked for others:

-I know og:image and og:image:url are the same, but apparently it was a solution for someone else, so I kept it since everything is working now.

-Also, the Facebook docs seem to suggest adding the `og:image:height` and `og:image:width`.

-Lastly, the og:image:secure_url is needed if you're URL has https, instead of http.